# Putting a good friend to bed in an insult match

Tags: grammar, pejorative-language

A mate of mine is slightly larger than I am ( I could do with a few less pints a week, if you catch my drift?) and we give out each other every time we see each other. I like him really. Actually really lovely to everyone else. Great lad. Today we both agreed that we are going to do tough mudder... all signed up. I'm bricking it too so I thought I'd be nice and literally not poke his belly. The W anchor has just started on me via text and ( here's where I'd love your help) I want to a tell him that I forgot to tell him that he is fat today (sorry if this offends any one, but this is our standard banter) im battling grammatically and with this sentence... also I feel that it could be followed with a punchier ending.

Please offer up a line to end all arguments in which he might try rebuttal (he will) I'm not looking for anything hurtful nor am I looking for anything too... soft. Side with me on this one ladies and gents... he LOVES to give it out.  PS I'm not a bully and am slightly afraid that i will be called one... it's just that he was slimmer than I only 6 months ago before he discovered his love of pizza and milkshakes and walking half pace and making up excuses not to go to the gym xxx

Comment: Perfect example of my poor grammar. Ha.

Comment: Really, why do you have to be the one to break the truth to him? Could you allow life to be his tutor? If you were sure how to phrase it, you would have said it. If you plan to get more fit and ask him to work out with you, that's another thing.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your question.  You have both signed up for a run called the [Tough Mudder](https://toughmudder.com/june-promo?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=Brand-B&utm_campaign=tmf-june17-discount-USA&gclid=COT_8P2svtQCFdyEswodPL4PCQ) which is an obstacle course involving a lot of mud, for insane runners.  You are a bit scared, to put it mildly, and you want to warm up by engaging in some friendly but pointed trash talk with your friend -- Round One of the Tough Mudder, so to speak.

Comment: Oh by the way, in case you were feeling neglected, did I mention how fat you are?  I really thought I could go the whole day without saying it but as you can see I lost that battle. ;-)

Comment: This is not a discussion forum and we do not provide writing advice. This is a site for specific answers to specific questions about the English language - words and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

How about telling him that you are going to stay away from him in the race because if he falls, he will set off a Mud Tsunami, that will engulf anyone near him?

Tsunami, in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tsunami).

> A very large ocean wave caused by an underwater earthquake or volcanic
>   eruption

While this may not be technically accurate, I think it gets your point across.  He is so large that if he falls it will be like a tsunami, and the resulting wave of mud will cause enormous damage to anyone in its path.

Comment: Retarget one of [these](http://www.jokes4us.com/yomamajokes/yomamasofatjokes.html). :-)